# SQL Developer freezing with GC overhead limit exceeded error on MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, garbage-collection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to use Oracle SQL Developer with a MySQL database. I can connect just fine and I can execute queries, I can see the tables, and with a table selected I can click on all tabs fine with the exception of the "Data" tab. When I click on the "Data" tab, I get a message "Waiting for Editor to initialize" and SQL Developer freezes. After a few minutes I get a message "GC overhead limit exceeded" with the following stack

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2114)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1921)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3278)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:462)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2997)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2245)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2638)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.ResultSetTableModel.openResultSet(ResultSetTableModel.java:490)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.ResultSetTableModel.fetchNext(ResultSetTableModel.java:274)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.ResultSetTableModel$4.doWork(ResultSetTableModel.java:686)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.ResultSetTableModel$4.doWork(ResultSetTableModel.java:670)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:193)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:554)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I looked around stackoverflow andn google but I could not finf anything that works for me. I am running this on Windows 7 64bit, SQL Developer version 4.0.3.16, MySQL server version 5.5. I have added a line

```
AddVMOption -Xmx1024M
```

in the sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf file, as suggested here

https://codechief.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/configuring-oracle-sql-developer-for-large-files-fix-out-of-memory-errors/

and also added changed the initial and max memory allocation pool sizes in the 
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0\product.conf file to

```
AddVMOption -Xms512m
```

and

```
AddVMOption -Xmx1024m
```

respectively. I am monitoring the performance and I am not running out of memory, but the CPU utilization rate goes above 90%.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You need to edit the `sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf` file, adding the following line:-

```
AddVMOption -Xmx1024M
```

Comment: Could you expand on why you believe this to be sufficient to fix the issue?

Comment: jvm flags need to be set in the product.conf file, see the other answer - your answer was accurate PRIOR to version 4.0

Comment: This worked for me and the "GC overheard limit exceeded" error I was getting against a large oracle table and exporting it as a csv.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 parameters for memory in the JVM:

`XMS` and `XMX`.

`XMS` is the initial size, in bytes, for any JVM being fired-up in your machine.
`XMX` is the maximum chunk of memory you'd want to be available to your VMs.

You should try and increase (with step size depending on your machine) both values.

Inside your `%APPDATA/sqldeveloper/<yourVersion>/product.conf` set the `XMS` to any multiple of `128m` with the `AddVMOption` parameter.

You could use, for instance
`AddVMOption -Xms3072m`

With this parameter set you can comment out the values eventually set to `XMX`.
If you keep receiving the same error, keep on incrementing the parameter until it runs smoothly.

**BE AWARE**

If you, by any chance, set the value of XMS as some value greater than the available memory of your system, you'll receive another error when starting the JVM or any application that runs on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway to set the XX:+UseParallelGC flag on startup?
Might help your gc work more efficiently.